# For all $i\geq 0$, $a_i\geq 0$ s.t $\sum_ia_i=1$, then $\sum_iia_i<\infty$?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider a recurrent irreducible aperiodic Markov chain with states $0,1,\dots$. Let $a^n$ be probability of first returning to state $0$ at $n$-th transition. Then $\sum_ia_i=1$.

I could not see why $\sum_iia_i<\infty$. Or I could rewrite previous expression as $\sum_{k\geq 0}\sum_{i\geq k}a_i<\infty$.

$Q:$ Why is $\sum_iia_i<\infty$? This is basically asking for expectation being finite. This normally would not be the case.

$Q':$ To consider limit theorem of Markov theorem with solution to discrete renewal equation, does one need assumption $\sum_iia_i<\infty$?

Comment: The assumptions $a_i \ge 0$ and $\sum_{i\ge 0} a_i = 1$ do not imply $\sum_{i\ge 0} i a_i<\infty$. Consider, for example, $a_i = \frac{6}{\pi^2 (i+1)^2}$

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I agree on that part. Samuel&Karlin's Stochastic process book vol 1 Thm 1.2 does not have this assumption. That is problematic to me.

Comment: The assumptions "recurrent", "irreducible" and "aperiodic" also are not sufficient. A random walk on $\mathbb Z^2$ satisfies these conditions, but $a_n = \Theta(n^{-2})$. Is there some other assumptions in the theorem?

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Nope. Recurrence guarantees $\sum_ia_i=1$ and irreducible just means every vertex is as good as every other vertex. Thus it suffices to deal with vertex $0$. Aperiodic is the assumption to allow admitting limiting solution. I just could not see where $\sum_iia_i<\infty$ comes out of those assumptions. I guess, they assumed $\sum_iia_i<\infty$.

Comment: It doesn't come out of those assumptions. The random walk on $\mathbb Z^2$ is recurrent but the recurrence time has infinite expectation.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I see. Thanks. I guess that is an additional assumption then.